# How do I add a scroller to a Menu in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In flex 4 I'm using a PopUpButton with a Menu populated with records from the database.

For one of our clients, the data provider of the Menu has more than 50 elements.

When they click on the Menu it expands beyond the height of the screen without showing a scroller or responding to the mouse-wheel. So in effect there is no way to access the lower items on the menu.

So I need to somehow restrict the height of the menu and add a scroller.

The `rowCount` and `maxHeight` commands are having no effect.

```
var companyContextMenu:Menu=new Menu();
companyContextMenu.maxHeight=400;
companyContextMenu.rowCount=20;
```

The same code was working fine before migrating to Flex 4.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flex there is a big different regarding scrollbars between version 3 and 4.

First, please don't mix the halos and the sparks.
Then put a scroller-Tag around the menu, that should become a scroller.
Just the container Group, DataGroup, VGroup, HGroup and TitleGroup implement IViewport and can handle the scoller-tag ouround them.

So, put your menu in one of the container above. Is this not handle for you, please post your code.

BR
Frank

Comment: Thanks Frank, that's enought to get me on track.